# how can I get corners point from some windows region (HRGN)

Tags: delphi, graphics

I have some polygon region (HRGN), and I want receive array of corner points. How can I do it in simple way in Delphi

Comment: might be useful : [How to calculate an area of a Windows region (HRGN) in pixels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11543412/how-to-calculate-an-area-of-a-windows-region-hrgn-in-pixels)

Answer (score 0):

In general case, there is no way to retrieve initial polygon vertices from HRGN.
  Internally windows region consists of some rectangles.
Exact representation is possible for rectilinear region, but any slanted edge gives a lot of small rectangles (and slightly different polygons could give equal regions)

If your problem is to obtain a set of rectangles, then use `GetRegionData` function.